# How to create an object from an Element of a Map

Tags: java

So i currently have this:

```
  public static JavaFact register(JavaFact jf){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Map<String, Activity> activities = new HashMap<String, Activity>();
    Map<String, Activity> companyActivities = new HashMap<String, Activity>();

    activities = jf.getAllActivities //this is just to get all the existent 
   // activities into the Map activities

    System.out.println("How many activities is the user envolved in?");
    int count = input.nextInt();
    for(int i = 0; i<count; i++){
         System.out.println("Insert activity code");
         String code = input.nextLine();
         Activity a = activities.get(code);
         companyAcitivities.put(code, a.clone()); //the error refers to this line
    }
}
```

With this i'm getting a `NullPointerException` after running it on main. How can i solve this? What i want is for the user to insert the code of the `Activity`, and then add that `Activity` to the `companyActivities` wich will be the `Map` holding all the activities corresponding to the `Company` in question.

Comment: What line of code does the error refer to?

Comment: Edited with that info

Comment: may be the last one ?

Comment: `a` is null, simply. You are getting value from a map, where there may not be a value for `code` that user inputted.

Comment: You surely ask an activity that does not exists with the String you typed, so a is null and give NPE

Comment: What i don't understand is that if i get a System.out.println(activities.toString()) it clearly shows all the activities with respective codes...

Comment: As @azro also said ,the activity you get from code must be null. To check this you can put a if block checking activities contains the provided code and also print the activity you got from map for that code.

Comment: The problem is i really need those activity values to be stored on the companyActivities... Like the activities are all in a Map wich already has all the type of activities. After i do a activities.toString(), it shows me all those activities. Why isn't it getting the Activity? I can clearly see on my screen that the Activity has the code i'm entering...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid your NullPointerException try it this way, as others already recommended in their comments above:

```
for(int i = 0; i<count; i++){
     System.out.println("Insert activity code");
     String code = input.nextLine();
     Activity a = activities.get(code);

     if(a != null) {
         companyAcitivities.put(code, a.clone()); //the error refers to this line
     }
}
```

Comment: The problem is i really need those activity values to be stored on the companyActivities... Like the activities are all in a Map wich already has all the type of activities. After i do a activities.toString(), it shows me all those activities. Why isn't it getting the Activity? I can clearly see on my screen that the Activity has the code i'm entering...

Comment: Could you provide the string representation of your Activities-Map?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/c77ce007fe559581ced143833ad5ce99 It's in another languade but codigo = code , designacao = name, then it's just stating that Activity allows deduction, and then the tax deduction value.

Comment: I found a solution for you. Simply put this line `input.nextLine();` between `int count = input.nextInt();` and the for-loop.